# Elasticsearch mlt query returning zero results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use elasticsearch's [mlt query API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html), but when I execute it against my document I get zero results.

I tried this query:

```
{
    "more_like_this": {
        "min_doc_freq": 0, 
        "percent_terms_to_match": 0.0, 
        "ids": [
            4990
        ], 
        "min_term_freq": 0
    }
}
```

Also tried using `docs` instead of `ids`:

```
{
    "more_like_this": {
        "min_doc_freq": 0, 
        "docs": [
            {
                "_type": "mytype", 
                "_id": 4990, 
                "_index": "myindex"
            }
        ], 
        "percent_terms_to_match": 0.0, 
        "min_term_freq": 0
    }
}
```

And I attempted the above queries without explicitly setting `min_doc_freq`, `min_term_freq` or `percent_terms_to_match`. This didn't work either.

However, if I run an mlt query against `like_text` I get results, like so:

```
{
    "more_like_this": {
        "min_doc_freq": 0, 
        "like_text": "developers Developer engineer", 
        "percent_terms_to_match": 0.0, 
        "min_term_freq": 0
    }
}
```

I can also hit the mlt endpoint and get results, i.e. `http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/4990/_mlt`

Comment: Shouldn't it be "id" and "doc" instead?

Comment: Not according to this: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html

I would've gotten an error if that were the case.

Comment: Note that there, they have ids represented as strings, whereas your id is a number. Try changing them to strings as well.